# jQuery toggle class when div is on the left of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have small issue about jQuery.
I'm trying to create a website with a horizontal scroll layout. With this layout, I wondering if it's possible to toggle class when element goes on the left of the viewport. I would like to have div bigger when this div is on the left of screen and return to previous size when hidden by viewport. Almost like iTunes cover slide effect. http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-coverflow/. 
I know it's possible with vertical scroll using ScrollTop and offset functions with jQuery but I didn't managed to find a way to do that with horizontal scroll.

Here is the html

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

here is the css

```
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  height:100%;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  width: auto;
}

#wrap {
}

div {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

And here the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/x8x8z76a/

If someone could help me I would be very grateful.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you know that it's possible with scrollTop, the only thing that you need is to know that there's also something like [scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/).

Comment: Okay thank you, sorry for misunderstanding but actually, I don't know how to apply that with my layout. I just know how to scroll to a div but I don't know how to run function when scroll to div. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sdghasemi/w8z4ccfe/) here.

you can easily modify `nearOffsetPixels` if you want to add/remove detection accuracy.

JS:

```
var lastScrollLeft = 0;
var divOffsetRight = $('#9').offset().left + $('#9').width();
var nearOffsetPixels = 5;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
    var documentScrollRight;
    if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
        lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
        documentScrollRight = documentScrollLeft + $(window).innerWidth();
        if((documentScrollRight > divOffsetRight - nearOffsetPixels) &&
          (documentScrollRight < divOffsetRight + nearOffsetPixels)) alert('reached');
    }
});
```

hope it works!